# VBA to filter comma separated values using multiple criteria in Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I'm new to VBA and would really appreciate some help.

I want to filter a column that has comma separated values using multiple criteria. At the moment, if I put more than one word in a cell, my filtering options/criteria are all of the words in the cell rather than coming up as discrete words/criteria.

Example: I have documented pets that each family has in a village. I want the filter to show separate criterion of *'dog'* and/or *'cat'* and/or *'horse'*, and not *'dog; cat; horse'* or *'dog; cat'*. If I wanted to know which families have a dog and I searched for *'dog'* in excel, it would only show me the dogs in families who don't own any other pets, since families that own other pets would come under a filter category of, say, *'dog; cat'*.

I also want to have the option of filtering more than one column in this way (with multiuple criteria) so that I can search which pets are in the village, which hobbies each child has, and which professions are in the family. For example, I might want to search in the pet column A for all the cats and/or dogs, in the child hobby column B for all the children that play basketball and/or chess, and in professions column C for all the architects and/or chefs and/or newsreaders. I would want my spreadsheet only to display all the families (rows) that fit all of these criteria.

Does anyone know how I can achieve this using VBA?

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

Say we start with data like:

[image]

and we wish to see only rows with either *cat* or *dog*  Since we are using **VBA** we can filter "by hand"

```
Sub MultiFilter()
    Dim N As Long, i As Long, v As String
    N = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    For i = 2 To N
        v = Cells(i, "A").Value
        If InStr(1, v, "dog") > 0 Or InStr(1, v, "cat") > 0 Then
            Cells(i, "A").EntireRow.Hidden = False
        Else
            Cells(i, "A").EntireRow.Hidden = True
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

This results in:

[image]

Comment: Hi Gary's Student, thank you very much for your reply. My spreadsheet will be used by a number of people who don't have advanced knowledge of Excel and who will need to use different filtering criteria on each occasion. Do you know how I can use VBA to code for a filter that will allow me to select discrete words? Thanks again.

Comment: You would create a *Userform* that you allow them to either create a list of words or select from a pre-assigned list of words.  The **VBA** code would then use this created list to run the filter.

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion. I want other people (who are not v familiar with Excel) to be able to add to and update the spreadsheet regularly, so I think creating a Userform would be a bit restrictive. I would want the filter criteria to update automatically, just as Excel filters normally do.

Answer (score 0):

You could also do this without VBA by applying filters to your headings and then adding 'contains' text filters, such as 'Cat'.

The limitation without using VBA is that there is only room for 2 criteria in the text filters by using the 'AND/OR' criteria.

This same logic can be used on each column. Hope this non-VBA alternative helps!

Comment: Hi Cruter, Thanks a lot for your reply. I will need to be able to filter using more than 2 criteria, and this option is slightly less user-friendly than what I had in mind. Thanks again..